# Invoke Rest API In a Spring Boot Application using command line input

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, rest

I am trying to invoke REST APIs in the controller layer using command line inputs from the user using a Spring Boot application. I am aware of `CommandLineRunner` interface. But according to my knowledge it can be used to run some code which needs to be run at the start of the application for once. But for my case when ever user input some command line values different REST APIs written in the controller layer should be invoked. Is this possible in a Spring Boot application?

eg -

```
user input - add 2 3
```

add 2 3 command should invoke the following api in the controller layer

controller layer

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public int addNumber(@RequestBody SomeEntity entityObj) {
//
}
```

Comment: Why not just write a command-line application using Boot in that case instead of forcing it into some REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use  RestTemplate  request the /add in CommandLineRunner

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `curl` on the command line to invoke a rest api